# Direct FM generation using varactor diode

Tags: diodes, resonance, frequency-modulation, varactor

I am trying to generate a constant 1 MHz FM carrier wave. I have achieved it via LC parallel resonance circuit. Initially I let the switch B open and switch A closed, in order to charge the capacitor. When it is charged, I open the switch A and close switch B, to fulfill the oscillation phenomenon.

[image: Resonance frequency formula]

[image: LC parallel resonance circuit]

I am trying to generate the same carrier wave using varactor diode, but unable to do so.

[image: Varacter Diode]

At 1 V reverse biased voltage, datasheet of varactor diode tells that it has around 440 pF capacitance. Solving two capacitors in series gives 220 pF, which on solving with 0.115 mH inductor, gives 1 MHz frequency theoretically. Why am I unable to get the result on simulation?

[image: Varactor diode datasheet]

Comment: The frequency is vastly different (2 caps in series) and there is no current transient (its the current through L1 that is important) to kickoff oscillation. You also seem to think this will create a carrier ...it will not. The oscillation will decay.

Comment: No doubt, the model for Varactor diode has some internal resistive components that dissipate away any initial excitation of resonance.

Comment: Why don't you choose a classical series or parallel Oscillator design and insert Varicap with RC values for isolation?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Please have a look again. I have just edited the question. Besides this is a classical parallel oscillator design with varicap. Is it not?

Comment: @JackCreasey Please re consider my question, as I have just edited it. 
https://www.qsl.net/ko6bb/varactor.html
I learned about this circuit implementation from this website

Comment: @glen_geek How to work around?

Comment: @JackCreasey How to get the transient current in varacter diode case

Comment: @user9181286 just put back S1 into your circuit with a resistor to limit the current.

Comment: @JackCreasey What is S1?

Comment: @JackCreasey Okay switch 1 :P

Comment: Those are only "oscillator" circuits in a world where coils, capacitors, and wires are lossless.  In the real world you need a *real* oscillator.  Seach on Colpitts, Hartley, "RF Oscillator", etc.  As pointed out in the answer you can excite your varicap "oscillator" circuit with a pulse; you should see a damped sine wave that'll give you an idea of the Q of the circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

This is not how to create a 1MHz FM generator but shows what works on a simulator using a 1kHz 1us pulse to energize the inductor with < 100mA with a Q of 2000 in theory. (10M/500)

In practise, you need actual RLC values for every part or use a CMOS inverter instead of a switch and clock.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Why are you applying specifically 2.9 volts?

Comment: @Tony It's interesting that you don't need a continuous osc if you want to do simple FM chirp modulation instead of ASK. So a simple current pulse to produce symbols may be quite adequate.

Comment: And which simulator are you using? I liked it

Comment: Falstad web javascript  http://tinyurl.com/yb2k2lkl  It's awesome but time scale is under options > or mouse wheel and shift or control  but no varactor model yet

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Why is it producing 30 to 40 Volts at output?

Comment: THe energy stored depends on the DC current at the end of the dt of the pulsed switch for V=LdI/dt  and THAT raises the voltage of the oscillation.

Comment: Next Change the clock duty cycle from 0.1% to 1% then reset and it rises to 210V.. Now have you learned how to compute DC ramp energy and LC stored energy yet?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Yes I do. You are taking voltage across the inductor? right? And also tell that clock of 1 Khz means, 1000 times a second, the switch is closed. Then clock pulse and 5 V DC adds up, meanwhile the switch is closed?

Comment: Look again. it was set to normally open 0.1%  1us  low resistance ( you can adjust which also affect current rate, when you point at part or wave the other lights up in light blue

Comment: Here's 100kHz at 10% 1us 1 Ohm  1Mhz http://tinyurl.com/y89zjhvr  But you have to use a Power Sch. Diode which is not carrying any current in this SIM

Answer (score 2):

Until a simulation was attempted (in LTSpice), this circuit seemed a simple one to excite.

Discovered some tricky interaction between simulation time-step and resonance that affected results. First, here's the circuit. It starts off at t=0 with DC voltage source at zero volts. The RC time constant (R=1MEG, C=1n) rises to +20 volts in about five milliseconds. This transient alone is enough to excite resonance. During this time, varactor capacitance decreases, which increases resonant frequency from about 52 kHz to 400 kHz.:
[image: varactor excitation]

A transient simulation shows the resonant voltage across the inductor rising for a few milliseconds while resonant frequency changes, then decays slowly as resonant energy dissipates via R1's damping effect, and possibly by dissipative resistances in the Varactor diode D2 model. Note the fine timestep of 5 nanoseconds - this simulation seems reasonable:
[image: envelope of resonance with 5ns stepsize]

 The *same circuit* with only the timestep changed to 150 nanseconds yielded a different simulation result, showing no resonant decay, and a distorted envelope rise - this simulation seems to have run afoul:

[image: envelope of resonance with 150ns stepsize]

 These plots don't show resonant frequency change (one must zoom in very far to see cycle-by-cycle period). One would think that a 150ns step size should yield a decent simulation, but it seems that an upper limit of 5ns does a far better job. Estimates of resonant frequency benefit from small step sizes. Be sure to limit your simulator to a small time-step.